# How do I grant the privilege of connecting to SSIS?

Tags: ssis, permissions, dtexec

Attempting to run SSIS packages using dtexec.exe, I got this error message:

```
Could not load package "D:\Filename.dtsx" because of error 0xC00160AE.
Description: Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "" failed
with the following error: "Access is denied."

By default, only administrators have access to the Integration Services service.  On
Windows Vista and later, the process must be running with administrative privileges in
order to connect to the Integration Services service. See the help topic for information
on how to configure access to the service.
```

Typically for Microsoft, there's no clarification about which help topic has this information.  Certainly the `dtexec /?` help does not.

Running dtexec from a command prompt launched with admin privileges, or from an application with admin privileges, did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I eventually found the solution on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213130.aspx).  To grant users rights to the Integration Services service:

1. Open Component Services; from a Run dialog, you can enter "dcomcnfg".
2. On the left-hand tree, navigate to Component Services | Computers | My Computer | DCOM Config.
3. Find "Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 12.0".  This is for 2014; I believe earlier versions leave out "Microsoft," so check under "S" if you don't see it under "M".
4. Open Properties | Security and for each type of permission hit Edit and add an appropriate AD group or user.  Be sure to check the specific permissions required, such as Remote Launch when editing Launch and Activation Permission.  If anyone knows exactly which permissions are necessary for running SSIS, please share.
5. Launch Services, and restart the SQL Server Integration Services service.

You should now be able to connect to Integration Services from within SQL Studio or dtexec.exe.

Comment: This works. I only need to enable our service account to have a LOCAL ACCESS under ACCESS PERMISSION section.

Comment: This did not work for me.    The account which runs SSIS has the correct privs, and so does the account that I want to connect with, but still I get the error.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this today, basically the user you are using has not allowed to use SSIS:

[image]

Here the steps to allow your user to SSIS:

1. Open a commend prompt as Administrator and type `Dcomcnfg.exe`
2. Go to Console Root > Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config > Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services > Right click to Properties

[image]

3. Now under the "Security" tab you need to edit "Launch and Activation Permissions" and "Access Permissions"

[image]

**Launch and Activation Permissions** should look like this:

[image]

while **Access Permissions** should look like this:

[image]

4. Now open SQL Server Configuration Manager and go to SQL Services > SQL Server Integration Services > Right click and Restart

[image]

Comment: Please summarize the steps here in DBA.SE.  Otherwise, link rot will set in sooner or later.

Comment: @Francesco - as Jon mentioned, adding actionable details to your answer will help future visitors whereas a link to a site that may go away at any time will result in frustration.